# Find extremal points in the closed unit ball of : $c$, $l^p$ $L^p[0,1]$ , $L^\infty[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I seek to find all extremeal points in the following closed unit balls:
All spaces are over reals and all sequences can be assumed to have real entries.

$c$ the set of all sequences that converge.

*intuitively I feel like the constant sequences 1,1,.... and -1,-1,... are the only extremal points but I cannot show this precisely.*

$l^p$ , $1<p<\infty$ The space of p-summable sequences.

*very stuck here, cannot even think of a candidate*

I have done (and am quite certain of) the spaces; $c_0$, $C[0,1]$, $L_1[0,1]$ so if there is any way to extend these results I can use those. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Ok so I can show that the extreme points, if any exist, in $L^\infty$[0,1] are those on the unit sphere. I suspect any function on the unit sphere to be extreme but I cannot show this yet.

Comment: You mean constant sequence is in $c$? Shouldn't it go to zero?

Comment: What was your results on $C[0,1]$ and $L^1[0,1]$?

Comment: $C[0,1]$ : the constant functions 1, -1. In $L^1$ its empty. $c$ as defined in my text is all sequences which converge, distinct from $c_0$, all sequences converging to 0.

Comment: A typo, clearly since 1, 1, 1, .... does not go to zero.  My definition of $c$ agrees with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#c,_c0_and_c00

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks, I realized I did not know about this notion after reading the definition of extreme points.

Comment: I think you should open a new question. It will incentivize people to answer and will get more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are considering real sequences. The modifications for the complex case are quite easy.

Answer for c: If $(x_n)$ has norm $1$ and $|x_k| <1$ for some $k$ then replace $x_k$ by $x_k+r$ and $x_k-r$ with $0<r<1-|x_k|$ (and keep all other coordinates unchanged) to get two elements $y$ and $z$ such that $x=\frac  {y+z} 2$. Hence the only extreme points are sequences with $x_n=\pm 1$ for all $n$. [ Such sequences are indeed extreme points].

In $\ell^{p}$ with $1<p<\infty$ every point with norm $1$ is an extreme point. Hint: There exists $n$ such that $|x_n| <1$. Try to write $(x_n)$ as an average of two sequences of norm $1$.

Comment: What is the definition of an extreme point?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $X$ is a Banach space, and $x\in \overline {B_X(0,1)}$ is extreme, then $\|x\|=1.$ This is so because if $x=0$ then if we pick any norm $1\ y\in \overline {B_X(0,1)}$ then $x$ lies interior to the line segment $[-y,y].$ And if $0<x<1$, then $x$ lies in the interior of the line segment $\left[0,\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right]$ (because $x=(1-\|x\|)\cdot 0+\|x\|\cdot \frac{x}{\|x\|}$).

So it suffices to check only the points $x$ on the unit sphere, and since  $\overline {B_{\ell^p}(0,1)}$  is convex, we may consider, towards a contradiction, $z\neq w\in \overline {B_{\ell^p}(0,1)}$ such that $x=\frac{1}{2}z+\frac{1}{2}w.$ Then, using Minkowski's inequality, $1=\left \|\frac{z+w}{2}\right \|_p \le \left \|\frac{z}{2}\right \|_p+\left \|\frac{w}{2}\right \|_p$, which implies that $z$ and $w$ are norm $1$ vectors and therefore in fact, that equality holds in Minkowski. And this can only happen (recall, $p>1$), if there are numbers $r$ and $s$ such that $rz=sw$ and since $z$ and $w$ are unit vectors, we have $r=s$ and therefore $z=w$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: You made a point to say that $\bar{B_{\ell^p}}$  was convex but I'm not clear on where you used this.

Comment: Also why does it suffice to only check the case where $t=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Ok I believe you are using the definition of strictly convex, the third statement here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space.

Comment: One last thing, is there any reason I could not just copy/paste this proof to $L^p$. They both have the strict convexity property..

Comment: @Muselive Yes that's right.